# Show null values in group by query as zero

Tags: sql, group-by, null

I have two tables, tasks and status. Tasks table have columns task_id, project_id task_content and status_id. Status table have columns status_id and status_name. 
I want to get query which takes all status names and counts how much are there tasks with that status names. My query looks like this:

EDIT: i forgot to add project_id. Query needs to check only tasks within one project.

```
SELECT s.status_name, COUNT(t.status_id) AS tasks
FROM status s
LEFT JOIN tasks t
ON s.status_id = t.status_id
WHERE t.project_id = 1
GROUP BY s.status_name
```

My query is working good, but when there are no tasks with one of statuses this status is left out from query, i want it to show zero like:

```
    status name | tasks 
     status 1   |  3 
     status 2   |  2
     status 3   |  0
```

but my query looks like this:

```
status name | tasks 
 status 1   |  3 
 status 2   |  2
```

Comment: `count(t.status_id)`  instead of `count(*)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i still get the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT s.status_name, COUNT(t.status_id) AS tasks
FROM status s LEFT JOIN
     tasks t
     ON s.status_id = t.status_id AND
        t.project_id = 1
GROUP BY s.status_name;
```

`COUNT()` never returns a `NULL` value, so you don't need any extra check.  It returns `0` if there are no matches.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone for help, i found solution. I will post it for everyone who will have same or similar problem in future. Using 'WHERE' mess up my left join so there is workaround:

```
SELECT s.status_name, (IFNULL(COUNT(t.task_id), 0)) AS tasks
FROM status s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks t
ON  s.status_id = t.status_id 
AND t.project_id = 1 
GROUP BY s.status_name
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION BASED ON ORIGINAL POST (BEFORE ANY EDIT MADE) :

Use column_name (i.e. `t.status_id`) inside `count()` :

```
SELECT s.status_name, COUNT(t.status_id) AS tasks
FROM status s LEFT JOIN 
     tasks t
     ON s.status_id = t.status_id
GROUP BY s.status_name;
```

Comment: Works like other query, but is there a way to show 0 if there is no tasks with one of the statuses?

Answer (score 0):

Try below- use `count(t.status_id)` instead of `count(*)`

```
SELECT s.status_id,s.status_name, COUNT(t.status_id) AS tasks
    FROM status s
    LEFT JOIN tasks t
    ON s.status_id = t.status_id
    GROUP BY s.status_id,s.status_name
```

Comment: still the same result, is there other way to show 0 when there is no rows with that status?

Comment: do you've any status 3 in your status table @iposave

Comment: Yes i have, but for other tasks within other projects, i forgot to add that i will edit question now.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT s.status_name, COUNT(t.status_id) AS tasks
FROM status s
LEFT JOIN tasks t
ON s.status_id = t.status_id
GROUP BY s.status_name
```

Note you need `status 3` this values in your left table also then it will comes to the name other wise it will not

Comment: still there is same result

Comment: i have error now with this query. But, i will dont know which one of status is empty, this is just example, is there easier way to show 0 for status which dont have tasks right now?

Comment: with out value in status field there is no way to show that status

Comment: I have this status in status table, but not in tasks table for now, until there is task put to this status.

Comment: @iposave if you have that status on status table then it should work cuase left join pick all the values of left table so status in on your left so there is no issues